# Tkinter makes buttons way bigger than expected

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Consider the followig code which makes 3x3 grid of buttons:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Game:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.geometry("600x600")
        self.options = dict(font=("Courier 14", 30), fg="black", height=200, width=200)
        self.buttons = []
        for r in range(3):
            self.buttonrow = []
            self.buttons.append(self.buttonrow)
            for c in range(3):
                self.button = tk.Button(master, command=lambda r=r, c=c: self.response(r, c), **self.options)
                self.button.grid(row=r, column=c)
                self.buttonrow.append(self.button)
        master.mainloop()

    def response(self, row, col):
        self.buttons[row][col].config(text="X", state=tk.DISABLED)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Game(root)
```

When I write `master.geometry("600x600")` and then `height=200, width=200` in `self.options`, I expect the whole 3x3 grid to fit in the parent window. However, when I run this program, I only see 1 huge button that goes way beyond borders of the parent window and when I press it, I can't even see the `X` that appears on the button because it's so far beyond the border of the window. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The `width` option represents the number of average-width characters, not the number of pixels. By setting the width to 200, you're requesting that it be 200 *characters* wide.

The `width` only is interpreted as pixels when you configure the button to have an image.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to calculate how many pixels wide 1 character is? If I'm able to calculate this, I can fit the buttons in my parent window.

Answer (score 0):

So I have used the `<Button-1>` event format, where when the mouse button (Button 1 is the leftmost mouse button) is pressed over the widget, the current position of the mouse pointer (relative to the widget) is provided in the x and y members of the event object passed to the callback.

I have not given any fixed `geometry` (width and height) to the master window, as the window will size itself according to the widgets inside it, and then set `resizable` option to `false` so that the window maintains its look.

You can give the button size as per your need.

These changes solved both the issues:

1. Button size issue
2. Button event issue

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk

class Game:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.resizable(0,0)
        # row index
        for row in range(3):
            # col index
            for col in range(3):
                self.button = tk.Button(master, width=10, height=5)
                self.button.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=8, pady=8, ipadx=10, ipady=4)
                self.button.bind("<Button-1>", self.callback)
        master.mainloop()

    def callback(self, event):
        # get the clicked button
        clicked_btn = event.widget
        text_at_row_col = clicked_btn.config(text='X', state='disabled')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Game(root)
```

**Output:**

> The 3x3 button matrix

[image: button matrix]

> The `X` text as you click a button

[image: text in button]

Answer (score -1):

Using Python 3.12.0rc3 , Windows 10.

> when I run this program, I only see 1 huge button that goes way
> beyond borders of the parent window and **when I press it, I can't
> even see the X that appears on the button....**

This will be caused on line 4 using width and height. You should never use keywords in `dict` parameter.

Using `self.buttonrow = []` and `self.buttonrow = []` doesn't do anything. It it up to you.

Comment out all five.

Don't use `master.mainloop()`. You already have  `root = tk.Tk()`, then add `root.mainloop(`). This will be entirely scripted.

**Noticed**, `self.buttons` is not widget. It is list.

The response() function in the parameter doesn't do anything, I removed `r` and `c`.

I replace `Button` widget keyword `command=self.response`. Instead of `command=lambda r=r, c=c: self.response(r, c)`

Add `width` and `height` on `self.button.config`. This will prevent  freezing or not response.

Also replace `self.buttons` to `self.button`.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Game:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.geometry("600x600")
        self.options = dict(font=("Courier 14", 80), fg='black' )
        #self.buttons = []
        for r in range(3):
            #self.buttonrow = []
            #self.buttons.append(self.buttonrow)
            for c in range(3):
                self.button = tk.Button(master,  
                                        command=self.response,
                                        **self.options)
                
                self.button.grid(row=r, column=c)
                #self.buttonrow.append(self.button)
        #master.mainloop()

    def response(self):
        self.button.config(text="X", width=200, height=200, state='disabled')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Game(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

It is up to you what the script is doing.